# How to save python --version stdout to a text file?

Tags: python, stdout

I have tried the command below in both windows and mac:

```
python --version > file.txt
```

which will create a text file but the file it creates is empty.

Comment: It doesn't output because it writes to the `file.txt`.

Comment: it will just be in the file, rather than output to STDOUT

Comment: `python --version` writes to standard *error*. The file is created by the shell before `python` runs, but then nothing is written to the newly created file. Try `python --version 2> file.txt` instead.

Comment: I think people jumped to closing this question because they misunderstood "output". It is actually the file that will be created empty. This is a valid question!

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue, and it looks like it only affects Python 2. I'm using the default binaries on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

`python --version` outputs to `stderr` not `stdout` so to capture it to file use this command:

```
python --version 2>file.txt
```